# How to handle large numbers?

Tags: java, long-integer, biginteger

I am trying to solve the following problem

> you should calculate the difference between the square of the sum of the first n integers and the sum of the squares of the first n integer.

When I enter a large number (e.g. 4094574264) the answer is negative. Why? It should be a positive number.

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
long input = scan.nextLong();
long answer = (input * (input + 1) / 2)*(input * (input + 1) / 2) - (input * (input + 1)) * ((input * 2) + 1) / 6;
System.out.println(answer);
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in this line

```
(input * (input + 1) / 2)*(input * (input + 1) / 2) - (input * (input + 1)) * ((input * 2) + 1) / 6
```

4094574264 is a 33-bit signed number, therefore `input * (input + 1)` will need **66 bits** to store, which overflows 64-bit `long`. That's not counting the series of multiplications later, resulting in a result much larger than 64 bits.

If you want to do such high precision arithmetic, use [`BigInteger`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/math/BigInteger.html) instead

Comment: you need at least a 131-bit type to calculate the above expression

Answer (score 1):

You, my friend, are experiencing [overflow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow). This is when there aren't enough bits to describe the number that you want to explain, so you end up going around in a big loop (hence the negative numbers).

The solution, if you wish to use incredibly large numbers, is to use the `BigInteger` and `BigDecimal` class. These are designed to create arbitrary precision numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Low-level answer:

The answer is negative because you're experiencing overflow. The JVM can only represent numbers up to a certain value (the maximum for that type.) If you perform any operation which increases a value beyond the maximum, it "flows over" the machine's representation capabilities and changes the number completely; in your case, to a negative value. The opposite applies to negatives: if I decrease a negative value below the minimum, it will "flow under" and I will get an answer that is a very large positive. Use BigInteger (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) for "large math."